# Unable to equip bow in Breath of the Wild

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Every time I reach over my shoulder for my bow, Link fails to grab it, and comes back empty-handed.

I've tried everything, including resetting the game. It's not on my weapon wheel either, but my inventory shows multiple bows.

I've dropped them all and picked them back up, it shows up on my back, but I simply can't use it! No matter what I try!

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this, as it's driving me nuts! Only reason I bought the Switch and you can't beat the game without it!

Comment: What arrows do you have equipped?

Comment: Have you tried equipping your bow from your inventory?

Answer (score 3):

As hinted by @Joachim in comment the most probable cause is that you don't have arrow yet.

At the beginning of the game you can find a set of 5 arrows by breaking the pots near the (north) entrance of the temple (near a chest with a bow inside, how convenient...)

Another spot for arrows is south-west of the Sheika tower, where 2 bokoblins have a bow and will drop arrows when killed, and there's a few arrow in the ground behind them.

[image]